# Embed SSRS report into web page without Report Viewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an existing web application written in VS2008 & C# where I need to embed an SSRS report into a web page.  The database/SSRS server is offsite and behind a firewall and only accessible via IP from the separate web server box.  The database box is running SQL Server 2008R2.  ***I cannot use the Report Viewer control as a solution.***

I have tried both the SSRS web service and URL access.  Using the web service throws errors when calling LoadReport and/or Render methods.  Using URL access generates an error for the path of the report item.  I have tried many different code samples and methods to resolve this with no luck.  Does anyone have a working code sample that I can use to get this to work?

Ideally I'd like some way to have HTML returned from a call that I can then place into a DIV tag or iframe.

Comment: How are you trying to use the web service and what errors are being thrown?

Comment: I've added a Web Reference to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx  Then if I set credentials and then call LoadReport("/My+Reports/the-reportname", historyID)  returns error:   The path of the item '/My+Reports/the-reportname' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. --->  I've been able to successfully load the list of my reports if I cut the path back to "/My+Reports", adding any report name to the path it generates that error.

Comment: Have you tried directly to the reports rather than My Reports? My Reports is user specific and may yield a clue.

Comment: ExecutionInfo ei = re.LoadReport("the-reportname", historyID);    This returns the same error.

Comment: Missed the leading / before the reportname.  ExecutionInfo ei = re.LoadReport("/the-reportname", historyID);   returns the error:     The item '/the-reportname' cannot be found. --->

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a sample it is working for me
>
> Web config ...

```
<!-- Reporting -->
        <add key="ReportingUserName" value="xxxxx\xxxx" />
        <add key="ReportingPassword" value="xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add key="ReportingDomain" value="xxxxxxx" />


     <endpoint address="http://xxxxxx/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig" contract="SSRS.ReportExecutionServiceSoap" name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" />

     <!-- Binding for Reporting Services over HTTP -->
            <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
              <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </binding>
```

> outputType ReportFormat i.e, Pdf,Image,Excel,Ffd
>
> deviceInfo contains the XML string for reporting services based on the
>   ReportFormat
>
> reportPath contains report path on SSRS server "/xxx/datarecord-Table"

```
  private SsrsResponse ExecuteSsrsReport(string reportPath, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters,
        string outputType, string deviceInfo)
    {
        using (var rs = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient())
        {
            if (rs.ClientCredentials != null)
            {
                rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = GetReportingCredentials();
                rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
                    System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            }

            byte[] result;
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;

            ParameterValue[] parameterValues =
                parameters.Select(p => new ParameterValue { Name = p.Key, Value = p.Value }).ToArray();

            ExecutionInfo execInfo;
            ServerInfoHeader serverInfoHeader;

            ExecutionHeader execHeader =
                rs.LoadReport(null, reportPath, null, out serverInfoHeader, out execInfo);
            rs.SetExecutionParameters(execHeader, null, parameterValues, "en-us", out execInfo);

            string extension, mimeType, encoding;
            rs.Render(execHeader, null, outputType, deviceInfo,
                out result, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIds);

            return new SsrsResponse(result, extension, mimeType, encoding);
        }
    }

private NetworkCredential GetReportingCredentials()
{
    return new NetworkCredential(
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportingUserName"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportingPassword"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportingDomain"]
    );
}
```

Comment: On the "using" line, the IDE highlights ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient as type or namespace not found.  Same with SsrsResponse in the return line.  Not sure why.

Comment: I fixed the ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient, I was using a Web Reference and not a Service Reference.  Still can't figure out what's wrong with "SsrsResponse" in the return line.  Anyone??

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke the same URI of report in iframe.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that iFrames won't work if accessed across different domains -- web service cross domain issues. However, if it's not an issue for the project that could work.